# I receive an error in pandas for my dataframe being too large, how do I get past this error?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm importing sales data into a Pandas Dataframe and when I reach this line of code, it changes the dataframe dimensions to exceed the limits of Pandas.

Size before error:
`Dataframe.shape` =  (13, 46)

I run the following line and the sizes change for the DF:

```
SandS = SandS.merge(StoreIDLookup, on = 'Retail Location', how = 'left')
```

DF size is changed to `DF.shape` = (13, 16428)

I then received the following error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-fc11ca88710b>", line 63, in <module>
    SandS.to_excel(writer, 'Sales Upload')

  File "C:\Users\ccorrales\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2189, in to_excel
    formatter.write(

  File "C:\Users\ccorrales\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 803, in write
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 13, 16429 Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384"
```

Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please make sure to [include all of the relevant code to set up the problem and create the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and the full traceback in questions. Specifically, what is SandS and StoreIDLookup?

Answer (score 1):

Python isn't the problem. You are trying to write a data frame with 16,428 columns to an excel file. The excel file format itself will not accept that many columns. As the error states the max column number for an excel sheet is 16,384. Most simple fix would be to split the df in two an save it into two separate sheets.